# How can one have right movement into diagonal collision boxes giving diagonal movement?

Tags: java, slick2d

Firstly, apologies for the long title; I could not think of a way to sufficiently cover my problem yet also compact it further.

I am in the process of creating a 2D game in Java with a character in the centre of the screen. My character has a collision box and I have images on the map (looking from above) which also have collision boxes. 
However, I'd like to be able to have a "slide" situation if a collision occurs into a side that is not perpendicular to my direction.

For example, if my character is moving east, and there is a wall to his east going in the southwest to northeast direction, instead of just noting that there is an object to the east and not moving, I'd like my character to be able to "slide" along the wall, moving northeast to achieve the attempted Eastern movement.

Is there any easy way to do this?

If it helps in any way, I am using Java Slick2D, and have the collision box of the character as a rectangle where he stands, and the collision boxes of other objects as polygons.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: Too confusing, is there a way to explain it better?

Comment: @smttsp Thanks, it's hard to explain. Perhaps this helps:
[link](http://puu.sh/nUn4w/dda0e41f90.PNG)

If I move my character left, I would ideally like him to not just see after a little movement that there is a house and he can't move there, but also to see that he can slide along the diagonal downwards and left, and move accordingly. Very similar to 2D zelda games, if you are familiar.

Comment: Keep track of position as well as direction. Probably you have a location matrix where you store the boxes. Based on direction, calculate if there is obstacle in a range on his direction. If there is any stop, else you can go. If you had some piece of code, my explanation would make more sense

Comment: But isn't that normal collision detection? How would this end up with my character "sliding" along the diagonal wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have solved the problem of identifying when a collision has occurred, the sliding motion can be achieved by calculating the component of the motion that is perpendicular to the wall and subtract that from your motion vector.
Say you have a motion vector v = (v_x, v_y) and the normal of the wall n = (n_x,n_y).  The normal vector should be of length 1. 
Then your new motion vector should be 
v_new = v - (v * n) * n. 
That in X and Y separately is 
v_new_x = v_x - (v_x * n_x + v_y * n_y) * n_y, 
and the same way for Y

Comment: Thank you. I was not previously working with vectors, but I think it'll be a lot easier to deal with, as you have displayed.

Comment: Actually, are you sure that the last formula is correct?
v_new = ( v_x * (1 + n_x)  ,  v_y * (1 + n_y) ), which will always have zero the x direction if the movement was only attempted in the y direction, but this shouldn't always be the case, as the sliding should be diagonal, i.e. with an x direction magnitude.

Comment: Sorry, wrote before thinking properly. So, it's v_new = v + (v * n) * n. That in X and Y separately is v_new_x = v_x + (v_x * n_x + v_y * n_y) * n_y, and the same way for Y

Comment: Yes, working with vectors often makes these kinds of problems more manageable. What's described in this question is an ideal inelastic collision. If you want an elastic collision (bounce) multiply the second term with 2.

Comment: Perhaps you mean   v_new = v - (v * n) * n? 

For example, if we're trying to move left ( vector (-1,0) ) and the wall is diagonal bottom-left to top-right, then the normal vector is (1/sqrt(2) )*(1,-1), and your formula with the addition would then give (-3/2, 1/2), whereas if you subtract you instead get (-1/2, -1/2), which seems correct: you slide down and left along the wall. (There is also a very minor typo in your first of the two comments where you've used n_y instead of n_x, for the benefit of anyone reading.)

Comment: If so, then brilliant, this seems to work for my couple of calculations that I've tried. Thanks! 

I'm not sure what constant/term you are suggesting can be doubled to create a bounce however, I would be interested to know?

Comment: The sign depends on the direction of the normal vector. If it is directed towards the object, a plus sign is actually the correct one. This is because (v * n) gives a negative scalar if they are pointing towards each other. The expression fore the bounce becomes `v_new = v + 2 * (v * n) * n.` You can make it even more general if you write `v_new = v + (1+e) * (v * n) * n`. Here, _e_ is the elasticity factor (between 0 and 1). Closer to 0 gives more dampening, and closer to 1 gives more bounce.

Comment: Would it? Even if negating the vector to point the opposite direction, this would also negate the dot product, so multiplying these two negations would overall not change the answer, I believe? In my example, the vector is indeed directed towards the object, out of the wall.

Ahh brilliant, thank you! I'll be sure to look into that a little after I have the foundations laid.

Answer (score 0):

Class `java.awt.geom.Area` has a method `intersects( Area a )` which should be useful for determining the "point" of impact, call it *P*. If the character's collision box is a rectangle and the obstacle is bounded by an arbitrary polygon you'll have to determine

1. the point or side of the rectangle participating in the collision
2. the point or side of the polygon participating in the collision

If side meets side (they should be parallel), the charcter can't move any more in the current direction; no slide should occur. Equally, if a rectangle side meets a polygon point, movement is blocked.

If a point meets a point, you might resolve this by (arbitrarily?) select one of the sides of the polygon and handle the situation based on that.

Finally, if a rectangle corner meets a slanting side, you'll have to analyze the geometry of this side. (Verify that a 10-to-4 side is met by the upper right (lower left) hand corner if going north or east (south or west), or a 7-to-1 side is met by the upper left (lower right) hand corner when going north or west (south or east)). Then you can determine the forced path along the slanted side.

While this sounds relatively simple, there may be much more complex situations lurking literally round the corner if the collision boxes of objects - polygons - may have concave sections.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for your answer; I am not a high enough reputation to upvote it.

I have chosen to go with the other answer, as its suggestion of switching to vectors makes a lot of sense to me currently. Regardless, you have my thanks.